# Google Cloud Vision API Permission Denied

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I was trying to run the sample app, found here [Github Sample](https://github.com/Batzee/cloud-vision/tree/master/android), I have created a certificate and created a API Key and applied as instructed. But when I upload the Image I am getting this Exception. I dont know where I have made a mistake. Have I missed anything?

```
failed to make API request because {
    "code": 403,
    "errors": [{
        "domain": "global",
        "message": "Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.",
        "reason": "forbidden"
    }],
    "message": "Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Comment: Any luck? I am kind of facing the same problem!

Comment: I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: @amalan-dhananjayan Any chance you have set the bundle identifier in the API key? I'm guessing this might be the same issue we are seeing for the iOS samples. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/issues/16 I will see if maybe there's an Android-specific set of client libraries we should be using instead of the Java ones.

Comment: Yes i have set bundle specifier in my API key, I am not supposed to?

Comment: @TimSwast Yes. I have set the bunddle name/Identifier and the SHA-1 key to create the API Key. I tried with the sample app too, with my own SHA-1 key. It is also giving the same issue

Comment: It is working for me. I am creating a Browser Key instead of Android Key under API Manager - Credentials while creating API KEY. For some strange reason, it is working

Comment: @TimSwast as stack_ved says the API is working with Browser key. But it is not the proper way I think hope you can fix this issue from your side in a proper way.

Comment: In fact in the link @TimSwast has pasted, i found this work around

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem.
but I solve this.

If you add Browser API Key, your code works well.

Comment: Your answer is correct. It is working but it is not the proper way, we cannot track data quota properly with this  quick fix. @Tim_Swat is working on this issue from Google. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: Works well and even tracked usage for my case @AmalanDhananjayan

Comment: How to get the Browser API Key.. I have my API_KEY only.. Please help

Comment: Using the Browser Key is not the real solution for using API keys

Answer (score 9):

I suspect that you are creating an Android API key, restricted to your app, with your sha1 fingerprint registered.

This is great! Unfortunately, the [non-android-specific Google API java client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client) doesn't yet fully support API requests for android api keys, like the [android-specific](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client) one does. This means that API requests aren't including some headers that authenticate the key/app to the API endpoint, which causes that error (note the `client application <empty>` in the error message - the `<empty>` would be your package name, if the request was formed as expected).

I'm still looking for what to do about that - will update if / when I find one.

Answer (score 0):

What all did you change in the android project? Make sure that you enable the cloud vision API and enable billing. All I had to do was add my API key in the MainActivity using the same sample from Github.

Take a look at my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH6MP.png)

Comment: mind sharing what you added as the application package. I am facing the same issue, billing is enabled, but every request fails

Comment: sample.google.com.cloudvision is what the sample came with I did not refactor the package name to my own. Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please help us solve this. I guess it should have something to do with enabling billing. I have created an API key and assigned it to the variable  CLOUD_VISION_API_KEY. Have Enabled billing and cloud api for my project as well

Comment: Are you using the Github sample? If not, check your permissions in your Android Manifest. They should be:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

Answer (score 0):

**some problem here, and i fix it!!!!!**

**just put Server Key!!**

[image]

**hope its help someone**

Answer (score 0):

I believe using the browser key would solve your problem. But the actual solution to this is using an OAuth Key. Like an Android App should do.

1. To do so go to the credentials section from the side menu in Cloud Developer Console.
2. Click on credentials drop down menu and select OAuth Client ID.
3. Select Application Type as Android.
4. Add a suitable name like Android client for Cloud Vision API
5. Enter your SHA1 fingerprint in the desired format. Using the
   mentioned command on screen.
6. Enter the package name for your app, can be located in the
   defaultConfig block of your gradle.
7. Click on create.

This is an excerpt form the full tutorial [here](http://www.truiton.com/2016/06/android-image-recognition-google-cloud-vision-api/).

Answer (score 0):

You may have also limited your API Key to only allow requests from Android apps. Changing it to `None`, it will accept all requests, however, this also means less security.